# CSS hover won't change TEXT color in Reactjs

Tags: css, html, reactjs

Everything (font-size, border etc.) in the hover works fine excepts TEXT color which will not change as it is inherit(don't why). When I use same code in jsfiddle with the use of 'class' instead of 'className', text color will change.

```
 <div className="search float-right">

                <input className="form-control"/>
                <a className="search-btn" ref='#'>search</a>

 </div>

.search {
padding: 10px;
margin: 10px;
display: flex;
}

.search input {
margin-right: 10px;

}

.search-btn {
border-radius: 10%;
border: 1px white solid;
padding-left: 5px;
padding-right: 5px;

}

.search-btn:hover {
color: #fc6d63;
border-bottom: solid deepskyblue 1px;
font-size: 20px;
}
```

Comment: @Juan OP uses React, which uses `className` instead as `class`, which is a reserved name in JavaScript.

Comment: @chriskirknielsen sorry I missed that

Comment: @hei Just to be safe, have you tried adding `!important` on your `color` property? I know this can be buggy in some browsers, as I've recently seen a similar issue in Firefox. // @Juan: No worries, it happens.

Comment: @chriskirknielsen   Hi, yes it works now. I am using Chrome, can I know why it happens? Thanks!

Comment: I haven't dug deeper into the issue to find out why this happens. Since it works with `!important`, this tells us it's probably a specificity-related issue.

Comment: @chriskirknielsen thank you